# Xcode6 tableview click + navigation controller don't segue to collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, xcode6

I've a problem in my tableview, in theory when I click in a row it should go to the other view, but for some reasons when I click nothing happens, I don't know why i try a lot of code that there is in stack overflow and in internet but, I still have the problem. Where I'm doing wrong?

TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AFNetworking.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int verificaConnessione;

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * blockLabel;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * notificationLabel;

@end
```

TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER.M

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import "NSObject.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "CollectionViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note;

@end

@implementation TableViewController{
    NSArray *Titoli;
}

@synthesize blockLabel, notificationLabel;

- (NSArray *)imageURLs
{
    if (!_imageURLs)
    {
        NSArray *imageURLs = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://i.imgur.com/RBGzfAT.jpg",   //accel world                                                          @"http://i.imgur.com/fDBv3aU.jpg",   //air gear                                                            
                      nil];

        _imageURLs = imageURLs;
    }

    return _imageURLs;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];

    Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            blockLabel.text = @"Block Says Reachable";
        });
    };

    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            blockLabel.text = @"Block Says Unreachable";

            _verificaConnessione = 1;

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nessuna connessione internet"
                                                            message:@"Per usare questa app devi aver abilitata la connessione internet"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    };

    [reach startNotifier];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];

    Titoli = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Accel World",
                                              @"Air Gear",nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    Reachability * reach = [note object];

    if([reach isReachable])
    {
        notificationLabel.text = @"Notification Says Reachable";
    }
    else
    {
        notificationLabel.text = @"Notification Says Unreachable";
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.imageURLs count];
}

- (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)operationManager
{
    if (!_operationManager)
    {
        _operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
        _operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    };

    return _operationManager;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];

    cell.textLabel.text = [Titoli objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (_verificaConnessione == 1)
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagefailed.png"];

        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
        cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];

        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
        cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSString *url = self.imageURLs[indexPath.row];

        cell.imageView.associatedObject = url;

        [self.operationManager GET:url
                        parameters:nil
                           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                               if ([cell.imageView.associatedObject isEqualToString:url])
                               {
                                   cell.imageView.image = responseObject;
                               }
                           } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Failed with error %@.", error);
                           }];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        CollectionViewController *collection = [segue destinationViewController];
        collection.valore = [Titoli objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }}
```

COLLECTIONVIEWCONTROLLER.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *valore;

@end
```

And this is my Storyboard
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ajf8.jpg

Comment: Did you make the segue from the cell to the next controller? If so, did you choose a "selection segue" from the list when you made it (as opposed to an "accessory action")?

Comment: I've selected segue from cell to che next controller, and in the list of "selection segue", I've chosen " show"

Comment: Does _verificaConnessione == 1? If so, you're setting the userInteractionEnabled to NO in that clause. That's the only reason I can see that you're cells wouldn't be triggering the segue. You should set the userInteractionEnables to YES in the else clause.

Comment: _verificaConnessione == 1 indicates that there isn't connection, so change the placeholder image; I've put the userInteractionEnabled to YES, and not activated yet. I've also commento the if build with the code that is in the else but nothing.

Comment: You should implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and just put a log in there to see if it's called. That will at least tell you whether the cell is responsive to touch. If it's not, then the problem is with the cell, not the segue.

Comment: Now I've added:- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetails" sender:tableView];
} and work perfectly, (the segue is made from cell to the controller), so the ObiWanKeNerd answer was the correct, thank also you for the information^^

Comment: His answer is a work around. If you correctly made the segue from the cell, you shouldn't need any code, for the segue to be performed. Without actually seeing your app though, I can't tell what you did wrong.

Comment: I know that is a work around, but if I throw away that part, the click doesn't work anymore. Forma the segue I've clicked with the right button of the mouse on the "prototype cell", then I've clicked in the CollectionViewController. I don't know why if I take off that code doesn't work anymore

Comment: I don't know either, I just wanted to make sure you realized it is a work around, and that the next time you make a segue from a cell, you don't automatically assume that you need code to make it work. I've made more than 50 projects with segues attached to cells, and never had a case where the segue didn't work without code. It sounds like you did everything correctly, so it's baffling to me why it doesn't work.

Comment: I thank you all, I rewrote all the code , putting the UIImage and UILabel in the controller perfectly and now I do not know why, but now I have too much space in the cells and the text does not wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and within this method use for example `performSegueWithIdentifier` which identifier should be `"ShowDetails"` as it's written in your code

Comment: This is necessary only if the segue was made from the controller, not the cell.

Comment: I can't vote up because my reputation is too low, however thank very much for the answer.